# Using expand/collapsed on a maximized window work only once

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a window which I maximize after it is shown. Now my customer needs to minimize/maximize it so I added the minimize/maximize tools like so

```
tools:[{
    type: 'minimize',
    handler: function(event, target, owner, tool){
        owner.up('window').collapse();
    }
},{
    type: 'maximize',
    handler: function(event, target, owner, tool){
        owner.up('window').expand();

    }
}]
```

This works fine for one time. After that the minize button does nothing and the window stays maximized. It work again for one time when I close and reopen the window so it seems to be a sortt of reference problem. The console prints no error.

Comment: Perhaps this can be helpful: http://jsfiddle.net/existdissolve/nxuyu/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this doesn't help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. You expand the Window ExtJS doesn't reset the `isCollapsingOrExpanding` property which cause that all other expand/collapse operations are aborted. You can try to reset it yourself

```
handler: function(event, target, owner, tool){
    owner.up('window').expand();
    owner.up('window').isCollapsingOrExpanding = 0;
}
```

This is untested but it should work for you. You should mark this line and check with every ExtJS update if the issue is fixed in the framework.

Comment: this doesn't work still in 2016, version 6.0. Nice workaround though